# Strange behavior with nested arrays

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose I have a nested array, `foo`:

```
>>> foo = [[" ", " "], [" ", " "]]
```

Say I want to change element `0` of array `0`. I would do it like this:

```
>>> foo[0][0] = "a"
>>> print foo
[["a", " "], [" ", " "]]
```

Suppose instead `foo` is equal to this:

```
>>> foo2 = [[" "] * 2] * 2
```

If I print `foo2`, I'll still get the same result as the original `foo`:

```
>>> print foo2
[[" ", " "], [" ", " "]]
```

If I try to change an element in `foo2` though, I'll get this result:

```
>>> foo2[0][0] = "a"
>>> print foo2
[["a", " "], ["a", " "]]
```

As you can see, instead of replacing just element `0` of array `0`, it replaced element `0` in all of the arrays. What causes this strange behavior?

Comment: print `foo2[0] is foo2[1]` in your shell

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So, when I try to modify one array, I get the same result for all arrays?

Comment: yes, you are creating a pointer to the same object so one change will effect all.

Comment: while it may make sense that this creates references to lists rather than copies it is certainly counterintuitive - I would have expected this to create exactly the same structure as foo, since this is a pretty standard way to initalize things in python

Comment: @gkusner, this is not a standard way at all when creating lists

Comment: @SteveJohnson, the answer posted is incorrect, the string has nothing to do with the changes, it is the list that is changing